# Git adding "-->" to my code

Tags: git, github

I have a Github repo that I am the sole contributor to. Occasionally, when I make a change locally, commit, then push, git will add a "-->" in a file somewhere randomly. It's not a merge conflict because I don't have merge conflicts - I make all my changes locally then just push the changes to my repo, and I never fetch/pull from this specific repo. How does this random string make it into the file?

Comment: Check your editor settings. It's not a git.

Comment: Maybe you have some hooks that cause this behaviour? Check your hooks under `.git/hooks/

Comment: @zarathustra what exactly should I be looking for? There are a bunch of files in there but I'm not sure what they do.

Comment: Can you post an example of code (the entire file contents) where that has happened? We may be able to see something that is triggering it, eg. the beginning of an "<!--" HTML comment being auto-closed.

Comment: Once they are committed, Git literally *can't* modify any of your files. The reason is that they are obtained by their cryptographic hash ID, which is computed from their contents. The commit stores the hash ID, and other parts of Git store the contents under that hash ID. To get the file back, Git reads out the hash ID and then extracts the object-contents using that ID. If the contents' extracted checksum fails to match, Git declares the object to be corrupted. What *can* happen is that something else (not part of Git itself) can tweak the *work tree* versions of files.